# Detect if another button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a bunch of buttons with the id btn1, btn2 , btn3 etc. and i want to change the background when one button is clicked, for example if btn1 is pressed it gets black but when btn2 is pressed that gets black and btn1 goes back to its original state.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
#background-buttons { text-align: right; }
#background-buttons button {
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border:  none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
#background-buttons #activated { background-color: #000; }
#background-buttons button:hover { background-color: #555; }
#background-buttons button:active { background-color: #333; }
```

```html
    <div id="background-buttons">
    <button id="btn1" onclick="change()">1</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="change()">2</button>
    <button id="btn3" onclick="change()">3</button>
    <button id="btn4" onclick="change()">4</button>
    <button id="btn5" onclick="change()">5</button>
    <button id="btn6" onclick="change()">6</button>
    <button id="btn7" onclick="change()">7</button>
    <button id="btn8" onclick="change()">8</button>
    <button id="btn9" onclick="change()">9</button>
    <button id="btn10" onclick="change()">10</button>
  </div>
```

[This code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nfL71fh/1/)

Comment: What JavaScript have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `button` is clicked loop through all buttons, set their `backgroundColor` to `#222` and set the `backgroundColor` of the one that was clicked to something else.

Also, in the markup when you call the function `change()`, pass a parameter `this`,i.e, `change(this)`.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/8nfL71fh/4/)**</kbd>

```js
// el is the button that was clicked
function change(el) {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  // loop through all buttons
  for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    // if the current button is the one that was clicked change its color to 'plum', else '#222'
    all[i].style.backgroundColor = all[i] == el ? 'plum' : '#222'
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
#background-buttons {
  text-align: right;
}
#background-buttons button {
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
#background-buttons button:hover {
  background-color: #555 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-buttons">
  <button id="btn1" onclick="change(this)">1</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="change(this)">2</button>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="change(this)">3</button>
  <button id="btn4" onclick="change(this)">4</button>
  <button id="btn5" onclick="change(this)">5</button>
  <button id="btn6" onclick="change(this)">6</button>
  <button id="btn7" onclick="change(this)">7</button>
  <button id="btn8" onclick="change(this)">8</button>
  <button id="btn9" onclick="change(this)">9</button>
  <button id="btn10" onclick="change(this)">10</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than setting the property directly and looping, much simpler to add  and remove a class, e.g. remove the class from `'input.selectedClass'` and then `this.addClass('selectedClass')`. The OP may need add/remove class functions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class to style the selected button appropriately:

```
.selectedButton {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Create some library functions to add and remove a class:

```
var util = {dom:{}};

util.dom.hasClassName = function(el, cName) {
    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

util.dom.addClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (!util.dom.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = util.trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
}

util.dom.removeClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (util.dom.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = util.trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}


/* Remove leading and trailing whitespace and reduce
** multiple intermediate whitespaces to a single space
*/
util.trim = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}
```

Change the listeners so they passes a reference to the clicked button:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="change(this)">1</button>
```

Now when a button is clicked you can do:

```
function change(target) {
    var el = document.querySelector('button.selectedButton');
    if (el) util.dom.removeClassName(el, 'selectedButton');
    util.dom.addClassName(target, 'selectedButton');
}
```

It would be better to put a single listener on a parent element and use the related event's *target* property to find the button that was clicked. Also, you can remember the last button that the class was added to so you don't have to search for it next time. But that won't work if you are setting a selected button at the server.